# After full disk encryption: set output for successfull password

Tags: boot, encryption

I recently set-up a new Ubuntu 22.04 system with full disk encryption
following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019). Everything seems to work fine.

However, the UX is not perfect. Upon start-up I get prompted to enter my passphrase. After I entered it, nothing happens for a about two minutes. Then Ubuntu finally boots. This still makes me nervous each time, not knowing what's going on. Is there any way to set/manipulate the prompt to immediately print something like "Passphrase accepted. Now booting" in that case?

That tiny detail would make my life more calm I guess.

Comment: Is it showing a "splash" image? Pressing esc might toggle to text output. Delete the `quiet` & `splash` boot codes if they're there? Not sure if there's a verbose code. But something sounds like it's hanging, two minutes of nothing doesn't sound usual... unless it takes that long just to process the luks key - that's changeable. Could intentionally enter a wrong password to test how long that takes?

Comment: If you mean the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`  settings by `boot codes` then yes, they are there, but changing them only changes the stuff happening AFTER I successfully entered the passphrase. Pressing ESC while getting the passphrase-prompt and a wrong passphrase have the same effect: I get into GRUB prompt ("Minimal BASH-like line editing is upported ... grub>")

Comment: Must be grub asking for the password, my last install didn't quite do that, it must've already been through and onto the boot partition. Pressing ESC would toggle between the gui/splash screen asking for the password and some boot messages